# Static const data member defined in another file

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I'm working on a static analyzer for C++11. There is an interaction between static const members of a class and linkage for which I am not sure whether it is defined. My static analyzer should warn for it only if this construct is not defined.

The example is this one:

in file f1.cpp:

```
struct Foo {
    static const int x = 2;
};

int main(void) {
    return *&Foo::x;
}
```

and in file f2.cpp:

```
struct Foo {
    static int x;
};

int Foo::x;
```

The two files compiled and linked with `clang++ -std=c++11 -Weverything f1.cpp f2.cpp` cause no warning and produce a binary that returns 0. The same files when compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic f1.cpp f2.cpp` cause no warning and return 2.

My intuition is that this program is ill-defined but no warning is required, as:

- both names Foo::x have external linkage following N3376[basic.link]p5:

  > In addition, a member function, static data member,[...]
  >   has the typedef name for linkage purposes (7.1.3), has external linkage if the name of the class has external
  >   linkage.
- but they break the N3376[basic.link]p10 requirement:

  > After all adjustments of types (during which typedefs (7.1.3) are replaced by their definitions), the types
  >   specified by all declarations referring to a given variable or function shall be identical [...] A violation of this rule on type identity does not require a diagnostic.

To be 100% sure about this, a definition for these "all adjustments of types" is needed, but seems nowhere to be found in the C++11 standard. Is there any, and is the reasoning above correct?

Comment: See [§basic.def.odr/p5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.def.odr#5) specifically [5.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.def.odr#5.1): `There can be more than one definition of a class type` ... `each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an ODR violation. The Foo type has different declarations in each file.

One definition says x is declared with external linkage (can be anything, determined when linking) and the other that it's a compile-time constant with value 2.

Comment: Isn't this allowed by N3376[class.static.data]p1 ?

> A static data member is not part of the subobjects of a class.

Comment: @Szm: There is an ODR violation for `Foo::x`, Now you may consider that `class Foo` is ok, and only static part is problematic, but anyway the program is ill-formed.

Comment: @szm Subobjects do not matter here. I've expanded the answer a bit.

Comment: @Jarod42: following N3376[class.static.data]p2: "The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is not a definition [ ... ]" so file1.cpp contains no definition for `Foo::x` and file2.cpp contains one definition of `Foo::x`. I don't see why `Foo::x` violates ODR here.